# Glob.glob multiple dataframe to calculate add in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a newbie in python. I have a hundred dataframe.
My data looks like this:

```
Test1.csv
Test2.csv
Test3.csv
```

All files, the structured data is the same. for example:

```
a.set_index('OD', inplace=True)
a
OD  B1  B2  B3       
B1  1   1   1
B2  1   1   1
B3  1   1   1

b.set_index('OD', inplace=True)
b  
OD  B1  B2  B3
B1  2   2   2
B2  2   2   2
B3  2   2   2

c.set_index('OD', inplace=True)
c
OD  B1  B2  B3
B1  3   3   3
B2  3   3   3
B3  3   3   3

d = a + b + c
d
OD  B1  B2  B3
B1  6   6   6
B2  6   6   6
B3  6   6   6
```

How to calculate `add`  in elegant way multiple dataframe using :

```
files = glob.glob("test*.csv")
for f in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    df.set_index('OD', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do `concat` then `sum`

```
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f,index_col=0) for f in files] ).sum(level=0)
```

Or

```
import functools 
import operator
functools.reduce(operator.add,[pd.read_csv(f,index_col=0) for f in files])
```

Comment: thank you so much. How to consider OD col as an index? because OD col got multiplied example B1B1B1